Adding Confidence Interval in Mixed Model in R
I am looking to have confidence intervals plotted in baseR/ggplot. My mixed model code is: model<- lmer(sla~ari + (1|pid), data = IESMS ) (where I am trying to visualize if aridity index (ari) has effects on specific leaf area (sla), and pid is population id as a random effect.
How do I get to a plot that looks something like this? enter image description here
